# Setup an existing django docker project in my locale machine

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, docker, drone.io

I have a django project in github from my client. That project developed by using below technologys: 
 1. AWS EC2
 2. Docker
 3. Drone

And inside the poject i have a docker-compose file and a .drone.yml file.
But the prolem is how can i start developing the project in my locale machine.
I have downloaded the project, and i can run it but i cann't manage the docker and drone. So can you please help me to setup my project with docker and drone. I'm spending a lot's of time. 
[image: <code>enter image description here</code>]

Comment: Please share some code and also the structure of the project?

Comment: Start from here - https://docs.docker.com/get-started/

Comment: I would suggest completely ignoring Docker and building out the Django application locally, using a Python virtual environment for local isolation.  Only once the actual application is basically working and tested is it worth thinking about Docker.  Docker's [official tutorial on building and running custom images](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/) is required reading, and is also Python-based.

Answer (score 0):

If you want debug your application is just make a runserver in manage.py.
If you want start a container for your .yml file, you need run with docker-compose:

```
docker-compose -f .drone.yml up
```

Check if the configurations in your .yml are for your local envionment.

I hope that helps.